# Add user back to array and put to front

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a regret button, kind of like in the tinder app.
I want this button to look at the last removed user from the array, and put it back into view.

I have tried with this code, which adds to user back to the queue, but not when pressing. The user will be put at index 0, which is next in line. If I switch out the index, the app crashes so I assume another way has to be done.

Furthermore, the button can be pressed multiple times, and the user will appear multiple times in the view. You can see the commented code in the if statement, where I tried to solve this

```
fabRegret.setOnClickListener {

            if (rowItems.size != 0)//&& rowItems[0] != lastDeleted)
                rowItems.add(0, lastDeleted!!)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "User added to queue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            cardAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged() //undo button can be pressed multiple times to add same person again
        }
```

For clarifitcation:

```
rowItems = ArrayList()
lastDeleted = rowItems.removeAt(0)
```

Comment: It sounds to me that you are trying to implement an "undo" feature. Perhaps, implementing the Command Pattern would be a best fit for what you are traing to implement: https://matt.berther.io/2004/09/16/using-the-command-pattern-for-undo-functionality/

Comment: Worse case scenario, perhaps you should try a Stack instead of an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would please you to ask questions more precisely. I'm not sure if the following answer can help to solve your problem.

As both commentators already said, there are multiple ways to implement an **Undo / History Behaviour**.

---

## 1. Design Pattern

I recommend you to use the command design pattern, as [acarlstein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941222/add-user-back-to-array-and-put-to-front#comment98536136_55941222) already suggested.
[Here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command) is another link I can recommend.

---

## 2. Stack (duplicates)

If you want to implement it the quick & easy way, you could use a Stack instead of an ArrayList.
It's a LIFO (Last In - First Out) Storage.

You can implement the *Stack* (can hold duplicates) as follows:

```
val stack = stackOf(itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree)
stack.push(itemFour)
val item = stack.pop() // itemFour
```

But as I understand your question, you don't want to have duplicates in your history.

---

## 3. Stack adaption (no duplicates)

Without duplicates, you can adapt the *Stack* and override it's `push()` method to avoid duplicates.

Like this:

```
class UniqueStack<E> : Stack<E>() {
    override fun push(item : E) : E {
        // when item is already part of the stack, push it to the top
        if (contains(item)) remove(item)
        return super.push(item)
    }
}
```

An implementation could look like:

```
val history = UniqueStack<Int>()
history.push(1) // [1]
history.push(1) // [1]
history.push(2) // [1, 2]
history.push(1) // [2, 1]
history.push(1) // [2, 1]

println(history)            // prints "[2, 1]"
println(history.pop())  // prints "1"
println(history)            // prints "[2]"
```

---

I hope I was able to help you.